# 'e24PaymentPipe' cannot be resolved to payment type

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm using Tomcat 6 to run a payment script written in Java. This involves running a basic `.jsp` file and importing some `.class` files that then redirect the user to the payment platform. Easy.

The problem is .. try as I may, I just can't get the import bit to work (or so it seems).

Directory structure (reference dir = `/usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/benefit/`):

```
/index.jsp
/WEB-INF/classes/com/aciworldwide/commerce/gateway/plugins/e24PaymentPipe.class
...
```

And my **index.jsp** file looks like so:

```
<%@ page import="com.aciworldwide.commerce.gateway.plugins.*" %>
<%
try {
    /*
     * Request the transaction details first so that the payment can be tracked
     */
    String paymentid=request.getParameter("pid");
    String amount=request.getParameter("amount");
    String manual=request.getParameter("manual");

    e24PaymentPipe pipe = new e24PaymentPipe();
    pipe.setResourcePath("/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/");

    // ... stuff

} catch (Exception e) {
    //Report the error using the appropriate name and ID.
    e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
```

Here's the error I get when trying to run this:

```
An error occurred at line: 12 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
e24PaymentPipe cannot be resolved to a type
9:  String amount=request.getParameter("amount");
10:     String manual=request.getParameter("manual");
11: 
12:     e24PaymentPipe pipe = new e24PaymentPipe();
13:     pipe.setResourcePath("/usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/");
14:     pipe.setAction("4");
15:     pipe.setCurrency("048");
```

**EDIT:** If you'd like to review the file permissions, I've pasted them [here](http://textdump.net/read/3094/).

Comment: instead of * directly use class name.I was having similar type of error before and i did like this and it solved.

Comment: @javaBeginner: Now I get the error message: `An error occurred at line: 6 in the generated java file Only a type can be imported. com.aciworldwide.commerce.gateway.plugins.e24PaymentPipe resolves to a package`

Comment: dunno. looks like the line with the comment :/